# Manipulating DataFrames with loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

Data Description:
I am having Two data Frames.
First DataFrame Contains the Names and Products
The Second Data Frame Contains ID, Name_Product, Type, Source, Target.

The source and destination are mapped and fed using IDs of second df after identifying the pattern of first dataframe

[My First DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cdri.png)

[Second DataFrame:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poIf5.png)

[How do I get an Expected Updated DataFrame like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HVlw.png)

Comment: It is unclear how exactly you want to put into 'Source' and 'Target' columns. In the third image, 'Source' and 'Target' are still NaN. In addition, first dataframe does not have 'Target' column, is this typo of 'Product'?

Comment: I am having it in my second Dataframe. I just want to map out the attributes and store the ids of them in source and destination.

Comment: Ah, I understood. third dataframe also include second dataframe so I was confused.

Comment: The second data frame should be updated where Type= Transition. No problem if it contains Nan in my source and Destination

Comment: In the third dataframe, 13 and 14 rows are same (ID: 1,6). How/Why the duplicated rows can be generated ?

Comment: my bad it should be 1,7

Comment: updated the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This full code will provide what you expected.
There must be many ways to improve this code. To impove your skill, I highly recommend you to follow how the code works. Then, you will be able to edit this code as you want :)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['raddit', 'dog', 'squirrel', 'cat', 'donkey', 'missing',],
        'product': ['carrot', 'bone', 'carrot', 'milk', 'missing', 'meat',],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,],
        'name_product': ['milk', 'bone', 'carrot', 'raddit', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'raddit', 'donkey', 'donkey', 'squirrel',],
        'type': ['attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute',],
        'source': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
        'target': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    }
)

# to make animal-feed dictionary
feed = dict()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['product'] in feed.keys():
        feed[row['product']].append(row['name'])
    else:
        feed[row['product']] = [row['name']]

# df3 is for only results
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name_product', 'type', 'source', 'target'])

# to find all the rows using animal-feed dictionary
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['name_product'] in feed.keys():
        animals = feed[row['name_product']]
        animal_id_list = df2[df2['name_product'].isin(animals)]['id'].to_list()
        for animal_id in animal_id_list:
            df3 = df3.append({'id': f"{row['id']},{animal_id}", 'type': 'transition', 'source': row['id'], 'target': animal_id}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        pass

df3 = df2.append(df3, ignore_index=True)
print(df3)
"""
      id name_product        type source target
0      1         milk   attribute    NaN    NaN
1      2         bone   attribute    NaN    NaN
2      3       carrot   attribute    NaN    NaN
3      4       raddit   attribute    NaN    NaN
4      5          dog   attribute    NaN    NaN
5      6          cat   attribute    NaN    NaN
6      7          cat   attribute    NaN    NaN
7      8          dog   attribute    NaN    NaN
8      9          dog   attribute    NaN    NaN
9     10       raddit   attribute    NaN    NaN
10    11       donkey   attribute    NaN    NaN
11    12       donkey   attribute    NaN    NaN
12    13     squirrel   attribute    NaN    NaN
13   1,6          NaN  transition      1      6
14   1,7          NaN  transition      1      7
15   2,5          NaN  transition      2      5
16   2,8          NaN  transition      2      8
17   2,9          NaN  transition      2      9
18   3,4          NaN  transition      3      4
19  3,10          NaN  transition      3     10
20  3,13          NaN  transition      3     13
"""
```

Comment: This works, But isn't there a way to just update the Second Dataframe, Instead of Creating the Third DataFrame?

Comment: @Hank Because I am using df2 in the `for loop`, it is impossible to update `df2` in real-time until the `for loop` ends. This is why I used extra dataframe, df3 to save only results parts and append it to df2. But actually, technically possible but needed extra processing. I want to remain it as your own.

Comment: I tried your code, it worked. Don't know why but I was not able to map the rabbit to the carrot with my Dataframes. trying to Debug the code

Comment: @Hank Oh my... there is a typo on my code, raddit.....should be rabbit. Sorry 